# Trying to alias a long command only gives me a partion of it

Tags: shell, quoting, alias, escape-characters

I have the following command which works:

```
ls -la | awk '$5 > 2'
```

I'm trying to alias the entire thing. 
If I try a naive way:

```
alias ll "ls -la | awk '$5 > 2'"
```

It doesn't work.

If I try to escape the dollar sign, I get only a part of the command and `ll` is now `ls -la | awk $5`

What should I do in order to define this alias the way I want it to be?

Comment: Use a function instead of alias, then you don't have to worry about quoting issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a shell function if your alias is more complicated than a simple command:

```
lz () {
    ls -la | awk '$5 > 2'
}
```

... or find a command that is simpler and fits as an alias:

```
alias lz='find . -maxdepth 1 -size +2c -ls'
```

The `bash` manual contains the statement

> For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions.

Related: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0):

escape, equal

```
$ alias ll="ls -la | awk '\$5 > 2'"
$ alias|grep ll                                       
ll='ls -la | awk '\''$5 > 2'\'
```

Comment: That's not the resule i'm getting. The result i'm getting is `ls -la | awk $5`.

Comment: Which shell do you use? I've tried it on mksh & bash.

Comment: @PanthersFan92:  How do you check it?

Comment: There is no need to grep an alias. This `alias ll` is faster and simpler.